# Redux props not showing in React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I can't understand why my Redux props are showing empty on the React component. This is the screenshot of the Redux state:

[image]

This is the component that visualizes. It is a child of a parent component that fetches the data and runs a for loop through the array of elements.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

 class ResourceCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { resource } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="resource-card">
        <div className="resource-card-header">
        <span className="res-span-header">{resource.header}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="resource-card-image">
        <img src={resource.image} alt={resource.header} width='300px' />
        </div>
        <div className="resource-card-desc">
        <span className="res-span-desc">{resource.description}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="resource-card-link">
        <span className="res-span">{resource.website}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ResourceCard.propTypes = {
  resource: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  resource: state.resource
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(ResourceCard);
```

While the css is being rendered properly, and there are no errors in the console, the content itself is not there:

[image]

What could possibly be wrong here?

EDITED: Adding actions code:

```
// Get Resources
export const getResources = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/api/resources")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_RESOURCES,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_RESOURCES,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

And the reducer:

```
import {
  ADD_RESOURCE,
  GET_RESOURCES,
  DELETE_RESOURCE,
  GET_RESOURCE
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  resources: [],
  resource: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_RESOURCES:
      return {
        ...state,
        resources: action.payload
      };
    case GET_RESOURCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        resource: action.payload
      };
    case DELETE_RESOURCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        resources: state.resources.filter(resource => resource._id !== action.payload)
      };
    case ADD_RESOURCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        resources: [action.payload, ...state.resources]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Parent component that runs a for-loop:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ResourceCard from './ResourceCard';

class ResourceFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { resources } = this.props;
    return resources.map(resource => <ResourceCard key={resource._id} resource={resource} />)
  }
}

ResourceFeed.propTypes = {
  resources: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default ResourceFeed;
```

And the component above contains this parent:

```
<ResourceFeed resources={resources}/>
```

Comment: please show actions code/reducer code

Comment: Provided in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  resource: state.resource      // <========== in this line
});
```

In `ResourceCard` component you are passing the `resource` props from two places, one from parent component and one from redux store, that's why.

Your component is expecting the `resource` value from parent, so remove this line:

`resource: state.resource`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am running a for-loop with mapping in the parent component of this one, passing down to this. Do I need to run another one inside of this one as well?

Comment: in that case you don't need to run another loop, can you show how you are running the loop in parent component?

Comment: Provided in the edit. And, btw, resource[0].header gives me 'undefined' TypeError.

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if it fails to solve the issue :)